# React sitemap.xml

Tags: reactjs, seo, xml-sitemap

I have a sitemap.xml file I want to show it when users hit [www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml) route. How can I do that?
I am using react and react-router-dom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already  have a `sitemap.xml` file ready with you, just put it under `public` directory. Anything under `public` directory can be directly opened by putting its path after domain url (even if you are using `react-router-dom`). So, `sitemap.xml` put under `public` directory will be available at [www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml) in your case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked actually my sitemap file was named differently. So upon hitting /sitemap.xml I was not getting the content.

Comment: For my case, I had to rebuild my app in order to work as I was using in production.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method.

**npm i react-router-sitemap**

Comment: Deprecated, not working anymore.